Redis server error: "Cannot assign requested address" under high traffic from Nginx to PHP to Redis
I'm experiencing an issue with my Redis server where I get the following error under high traffic:
Cannot assign requested address

my php code:
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
try{
    $redisConnected = $redis->connect('192.168.10.20', 6379,2);
    if($redisConnected) $redis->auth('myPassword');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
file_put_contents("redisErrorlog.log", $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}

This error appears intermittently when requests are being forwarded from Nginx to PHP, which then communicates with Redis. The traffic load is quite high, and the error seems to occur when Redis is under heavy load.
not all requests give this error
I tried to increase the linux server limit in ulimit -n 65535 and limits.conf and sysclt.conf but still has the same error.
my server software ubuntu 22.04.3
my server hardware is 128 RAM with 128 core cpu Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6438Y+
my redis.conf:
bind 192.168.10.20 127.0.0.1 ::1
protected-mode yes
port 6379
tcp-backlog 511
timeout 0
tcp-keepalive 300
daemonize yes
supervised no
pidfile /var/run/redis/redis-server.pid
loglevel notice
logfile /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
databases 16
always-show-logo yes
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error yes
rdbcompression yes
rdbchecksum yes
dbfilename dump.rdb
rdb-del-sync-files no
dir /var/lib/redis
replica-serve-stale-data yes
replica-read-only yes
repl-diskless-sync no
repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
repl-diskless-load disabled
repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
replica-priority 100
acllog-max-len 128
requirepass myPassword
lazyfree-lazy-eviction no
lazyfree-lazy-expire no
lazyfree-lazy-server-del no
replica-lazy-flush no
lazyfree-lazy-user-del no
oom-score-adj no
oom-score-adj-values 0 200 800
appendonly no
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
no-appendfsync-on-rewrite no
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof-load-truncated yes
aof-use-rdb-preamble yes
lua-time-limit 5000
slowlog-log-slower-than 10000
slowlog-max-len 128
latency-monitor-threshold 0
notify-keyspace-events ""
hash-max-ziplist-entries 512
hash-max-ziplist-value 64
list-max-ziplist-size -2
list-compress-depth 0
set-max-intset-entries 512
zset-max-ziplist-entries 128
zset-max-ziplist-value 64
hll-sparse-max-bytes 3000
stream-node-max-bytes 4096
stream-node-max-entries 100
activerehashing yes
client-output-buffer-limit normal 0 0 0
client-output-buffer-limit replica 256mb 64mb 60
client-output-buffer-limit pubsub 32mb 8mb 60
hz 10
dynamic-hz yes
aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync yes
rdb-save-incremental-fsync yes
jemalloc-bg-thread yes


I finally find the solution of this problem by adding the following to /etc/sysctl.conf
fs.file-max = 65536
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 1024 65535
net.core.somaxconn = 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 65535

then apply the config by
sysctl -p

